# Drawing X and Y axis using loops and strings

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I have this programming assignment which is very specific. I need to draw an x and y axis only using loops and if else statements, and the method it is in can only return strings, either of the axis characters, like |, or of an empty string, "". I have it almost correct, but I cannot understand why the y axis is not printing at x==0, but at x== -10. I would love a hint about how to fix this, I am sure it is something small I have overlooked. It does work it I return " " instead of "", but I am not allowed to do that. Thanks!

```
public class Try1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int height = 10;
  int width = 10; 

  for (int y = height; y >= -10; y--){
   for (int x = -10 ; x <= width; x++){
     DrawAxis(x,y);
     System.out.print(DrawAxis (x,y));

   }
   System.out.print("\n");
  }

}




 public static String DrawAxis(int x, int y)
 {
   if (x == 10 && y == 0)
      return ">";
   else 
     if (x == 0 && y == 10)
      return "^";
   else 
     if (x == 0 && y == 0)
       return ".";
   else 
      if (x == 0 && y >= -10)
        return "|";
   else
     if ( x >= -10 && y == 0)
      return "-";

return "";}
 }
```

Comment: What shape do you exactly want to draw?

Comment: I am trying to draw two axis lines (like a cross) in the middle of an 20 by 20 space.

Answer (score 0):

It is starting to print x at -10 since you are initialising the "x" variable to -10 in the second for-loop.

Also, it is the convention to use camel-case when naming methods and variables, therefore you should really rename the method to "drawAxis" from "DrawAxis", to aid in readability.

Comment: The method was named by my teacher, I cannot change it...but that's what I thought the rule was too!

Comment: I changed the width and height to be 20, so the middle is now (10,0) but it is still print in the same way. Could you explain a little more why it is doing that?

Comment: Have you changed the starting value of x in the second for loop?

Answer (score 0):

if (x == 0 && y >= -10)
        return "use many space before the symbole: |";
 compile and run, then see the position of |, then add space or minus space as required, (One little request, please give hint in the post for the line and parabola part , it will be much appreciated ) where parabola intersect the straight line.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, I replaced the empty string returns in the main method with a space instead, and it works marvelously now! Thanks for all your help!